# Form size and scale bug

Tags: c#, winforms, size, scale, auto

I am trying to create an application but after some time i couldn't resize my form with my desire when i type 2000;1000 (for example) it shows the grid lines like in the picture and sizes approximately 2500;1400
and its not the form itself but the panels inside it also getting bigger and bigger without my control when i type Ctrl + z to get previous size, my form and the panels inside also grown but the previous size was smaller.

i thought my code broken so i opened a new file but the problem still continued

in conclusion, i need help to fix this problem, any idea?

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haw0D.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your control (grid?) to stay the same size as the form, you can set it's `Dock = Fill` value.

You can also look at using a [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-arranging-controls-on-windows-forms-using-a-tablelayoutpanel) set the panel `.Dock` value to fill and use the `TableLayoutPanel` to manage they layout of your other controls.